# Cursor IDE and GitLens?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlens

Has anyone been able to use GitLens with Cursor (VSCode version)? Everytime I try, I get:

Extension 'eamodio.gitlens' CANNOT use API proposal: treeItemCheckbox. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares: [] but NOT treeItemCheckbox. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api eamodio.gitlens. Note that the cursor and control proposals are only available for built-in extensions

I already added treeItemCheckbox to the enabledApiProposals array in settings.json for the gitlens extension. I also tried 'cursor --enable-proposed-api eamodio.gitlens'. But I get the same message even after those steps.

In Cursor IDE (the latest VSCode integrated version), I imported all my VSCode extensions, but GitLens doesn't work. Under Source Control, I select Repositories and select a branch for comparison. When I try to drill down into one of the folders with a changed file, I get the message:

```
Extension 'eamodio.gitlens' CANNOT use API proposal: treeItemCheckbox. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares: [] but NOT treeItemCheckbox. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api eamodio.gitlens. Note that the cursor and control proposals are only available for built-in extensions
```

Comment: GitLens issues should be reported to its vendor, https://github.com/gitkraken/vscode-gitlens/issues and whether they support Cursor other than VS Code can only be answered by themselves.